# Identity Law - Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to wrap my head around the Identity Law, but I'm having some trouble.

My lecture slides say:
$$
A \cup \varnothing = A
$$
I can understand this one. $A$ union nothing is still $A$. In the same way that $1 + 0$ is still $1$.

However, it goes on to say:
$$
A \cup U = U
$$
I don't see how this is possible. How can $A\cup U = U$?

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/Venn0111.svg/150px-Venn0111.svg.png

If this image represents the result of $A\cup U$, where $A$ is the left circle, $U$ is the right circle, how can the UNION of both sets EQUAL the RIGHT set? I don't see how that is possible?

Can soemone please explain to me how this is possible? Thanks.
$$
    A \cap\varnothing=\varnothing,\\
    A \cap U = A
$$

Some further examples from the slides. I really don't understand these, either. It must be something simple, but I'm just not seeing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I assume that $U$ denotes some *universal* set, or *universe of discourse*: simply put, a set which contains everything currently under discussion.)

Well, $A$ union *everything* must be at least as big as *everything*.  But *everything* is, well, ***everything***, so no set can be bigger than *everything*.  Therefore $A$ union *everything* must be *everything*.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I feel silly for not understanding something so simple; however I doubt I will forget it now, since now I know the definition of U - everything.

Comment: @Anteara: No problem!  A general warning is that although there is an algebra associated with set operations (and it appears that you are learning it), it behaves quite a bit differently from arithmetic of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The right circle can't be $U$, because there are points not contained in the right circle. Remember that $U$ is the universal set: *all* points (in the domain of discussion) are a member of $U$.

If some set is missing any point, then that set is not $U$.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So, in the same way: If we have A ∪ U = U, A ∪ B is also equal to U? Because something and something must be contained within everything?
And: A ∩ U is A because, for example if A = {1,2} and U = {1,2,3,4...}, what is contained in BOTH sets is the same as what is already in A?

Answer (score 1):

Well $U$ is "the universe of discourse" -- it contains everything we'd like to talk about. In particular, all elements of $A$ are also in $U$.

In the "circles" representation, you can think of $U$ as *the paper* on which we draw circles to indicate sets like $A$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand it now; If the venn diagram has three circles, A, B, and C, then U must contain A, B, C, because A, B, C are 'written on' U, if we use the analagy of U being the paper.

I don't have enough reputation to upvote, however I do think you deserve one; if someone can upvote for me I would be gracious.

Answer (score 0):

The set equalities are explained by logic.

Let's call T ( or "truth") the proposition that is equivalent to all tautologies ( that is, all logically/ necessarily true propositions).

Let's calll F ( or "falsity) the proposition that is equivalent to all antilogies ( that is, all logically/ necessarily false  propositions).

You can verify, using a truth table that , for all proposition P

(1) P OR F is equivalent to P

(2) P & F is equivalent to F

(3) P OR T is equivalent to T.

(4) P & T is equivalent to P

Let's explain (1). The OR operator requires, to make a true statement, that 1 at least of the two proposiitons be true. Since the second, being "F"  is ( by definition) always false, everything depends on the truth value of the first : P. If P is true, it is a sufficient condition for (P OR F) to be true. If P is false, it is a sufficient condition for (P OR F) to be false. You can see that P and (P OR F) always have the same truth value: they are equivalent.

With this in mind, you can understand your set equalities, remembering the logical definition of each set theoretic operation.

For example

A Union EmptySet is , by definition the set of all x such that :

```
     (x belongs to A) OR (x belongs to the empty set).
```

But "x belongs to the empty set" is a logical impossibility: it can be replaced by the constant F ( = the false)

So, our set is the set of all x such that :

```
      ( x belongs to A) OR F
```

And, as we have seen, this OR sentence  is equivalent  to

```
      " x belongs to A ".
```

But " the set of all x such that x belongs to the set A "is nothing else but the set A itself!

Therefore : The set A Union EmptySet is nothing else but the set A itself.

To prove your set equalities, rephrase them using the logical definition of set operations and use :

- the constant T for " x belongs to U " ( U being the universal set) ; for " x belongs to U " is logically/necessarily true ( every element x being by definition an element of the universal set  "U")
- the constant F for " x belongs to the EmptySet"

Remark. It is somewhat misleading to say that the universal set U is everything. For all the sets you are dealing with are something ( even the empty set, which is not not nothing, but a set); but this sets are not elements of the universal set, they are subsets of the universal set. So U ( the universe) is, so to say " every elements" , but not really  " everything".